# Fonts not found in local .texmf-var but thy are in /usr/share

Tags: fonts, kpathsea

I'm having trouble using Droid Sans, and other fonts from the LaTeX font catalogue.

Using the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[defaultsans]{droidsans}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
trying out typefaces
\end{document}
```

I get the following output when I run `pdflatex test.tex`:

```
 ...
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)) (./test.aux)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/droid/t1fds.fd) [1{/home/martin/.texmf
 -var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)
 kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 DroidSans-01
 mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for DroidSans-01.
 mktexpk: perhaps DroidSans-01 is missing from the map file.
 kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
  )
 !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file DroidSans-01): Font DroidSans-01 at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Indeed, there is no mention of DroidSans in my local pdftex.map in ~/.texmf-var, but there is in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map.

What can I do to make pdflatex find the correct file?

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 with "texlive-full" installed.

Comment: Which texlive distribution do you have? 2015?

Comment: No, it's 2013.20140215-1.

Comment: I would first suggest that you update to the latest texlive.  See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/15925